# Is it right to put any question on hold when someone might be there to help?

Tags: discussion, on-hold

If you ask your question in your own words, that question may be put on hold.

Is it right to put any question on hold when someone might be there to help?

If somebody cannot understand the question, then that person should be asking for clarification rather than putting it on hold.

Comment: Putting it on hold is our way to give the OP the oppertunity to improve the question...

Comment: and if that person is not good at asking question then

Comment: Then they can follow all the advice on asking question provided in the help center. And read the comments posted to see if anything there needs to be addressed. And then can ask on the appropriate per-site meta for further guidance.

Comment: Questions that are unclear can't be answered. Therefore they need to be closed to give OP the change to make it answerable.

Comment: But person like you all are so good that you get an idea what a newbie might be asking. So you guys should suggest that person. And I think whenever we do editing we learn more. Suggesting that person how to ask will help.

Comment: Questions that are unclear garner guesses.  That's exactly what we want to prevent, and the whole reason for on hold.

Comment: @fbueckert I agree with you BUT think If question is related to my domain the somehow or the other I'll understand that person's question. or It might be that the problem which that person is facing, in my earlier days I also had. So I'll be knowing the ans which might help. And if question goes on hold then no other person can ans that question.

Comment: *That's the whole point of putting questions on hold*.  You *might* know the answer, but you have zero guarantee of that whatsoever.

Comment: @fbueckert but it will start generating the idea. That person will start thinking in some direction. When that person asked question he/she has no idea but when person like us started giving suggestion then it might help. May be ans will be not fully correct but IDEA will be imp.

Comment: The SE network is generally not for *ideas*.  It's for *problems*.  If the user cannot articulate that problem properly, then they need to expend more effort to do so.

Comment: @fbueckert In Some question you don't know the exact problem. If you know then finding out the ans is easier. And if person don't know what the problem is then that person can only explain what is been done by him. And is somehow unclear. then what will be done

Comment: If you don't know the problem, you shouldn't be asking here.  The base requirement for the SE network is *effort*.  By not expending the effort to articulate your question, or actually *find* your problem, you shouldn't be asking on the SE network.  You're disrespecting the time and energy of those who are helping you, *for free*.

Comment: @fbueckert sometimes it asking the right question is harder than giving the right answer :-)

Comment: This is going to sound blunt, and I apologize for that.  That's the asker's problem, not ours.  If you're going to ask experts for help, the least you can do is ensure the experts don't have to drag your problem out of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be assuming that asking for clarfication and putting it on hold are mutually exclusive.

Yet, if a question is unclear, it should be put on hold as "unclear what you are asking." Indeed, this is (or at least can be) part of asking for clarification.
If and when the question is clarified it should be reopened.

Put differently, when somebody puts your question on hold, they are asking you for clarification, as you suggest. Then, please, provide this clarification.

The question being on hold does not prevent OP or anybody from helping to clarify the question. If however it is impossible to arrive in a joint effort at a clear question, then it is unclear how an answer should be helpful.

Comment: I agree with you BUT think If question is related to my domain the somehow or the other I'll understand that person's question. or It might be that the problem which that person is facing, in my earlier days I also had. So I'll be knowing the ans which might help. And if question goes on hold then no other person can ans that question.

Comment: It is true that a knowledgeable person with good will can often infer intent. It can then be nice  to suggest possible formulations to OP; as opposed to just poking holes into the question as asked. (What to do depends on precise circumstances.)  It can even be appropriate not to close right away if there is a reasonable chance things will be clarified promptly. (This depends a bit on the size of the site; on a small site this is easier than on a large one.)

Comment: What however is a problem, is answering whatever one *believes* might be asked. This can lead to complicated situations, people talking sideways and so on. The question should be (reasonably) clear before it gets answered. To enforce this is the point of putting it on hold.

Comment: sometimes it asking the right question is harder than giving the right answer :-)

Comment: That's quite true, but does not really change anything for the matter at hand.

Answer (score 5):

You are misunderstanding what "on hold" means.

On hold means that the question **cannot be answered** or **isn't a good fit for the site you asked it on**. On over 90% of the cases, the question can be improved to fit the site. In which case, the on-hold status is removed.

When you ask a question on a Stack Exchange site, your question is expected to have value beyond just your specific problem, that's selfish. Instead, we expect questions to be useful for visitors from search engines as well.

On hold (and downvotes too, for that matter) don't attempt to hurt you personally, they are a tool to keep the quality of the site high. If you cannot deal with your question being put on hold, improve it by learning how to ask, or don't and get out.

Comment: sometimes it asking the right question is harder than giving the right answer :-)

Comment: So? How does that invalidate anything I said? We have a certain standard for questions. Questions which do not conform to that standard are temporarily put on hold to allow the author to fix them. If they do not fix the question, the temporary on hold usually becomes a permanent closed.